# Эквивалентность перечислений и объединений в качестве шаблонных параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, enum, union

```
#include <type_traits>

template<auto T>
struct A {};

enum class E {
    a = 0,
    b = 0,
};

union U {
    int a;
    int b;
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<A<E::a>, A<E::b>>);
static_assert(not std::is_same_v<A<U{.a=0}>, A<U{.b=0}>>);
```

Почему шаблонные классы с перечислениями с одинаковыми значениями в качестве шаблонных параметров считаются одинаковыми, а с объединениями - нет?

Comment: за что минус вопросу?

Answer (score 3):

Для того чтобы два шаблонных non-type аргумента, имеющих тип объединения (union) совпадали, они должны:

- иметь одинаковый тип,
- оба не иметь активных членов, либо оба иметь один и тот же активный член,
- значения активных членов должны совпадать.

[temp.type](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type#2.9):

> Two template-ids are the same if
> ...
> their corresponding non-type template-arguments are template-argument-equivalent (see below) after conversion to the type of the template-parameter,
> ...
> Two values are template-argument-equivalent if they are of the same type and
> ...
> they are of union type and either they both have no active member or they have the same active member and their active members are template-argument-equivalent,
> ...

В вашем случае два шаблонных аргумента имеют одинаковый тип объединения, значения активных членов совпадают, но объединения имеют разные активные члены (`.a=0` vs `.b=0`), поэтому шаблонные аргументы считаются разными.